# Почему не срабатывает else внутри цикла for (PYTHON)?

Tags: python, if

Доброго времени суток.

Есть список вопросов. В каждом вопросе первое слово - обращение по имени к человеку.

Соответственно, есть код, который проверяет первое слово в каждом вопросе и, если оно совпадает с заранее заданным именем, то выводится сообщение "Запрос к <имени>". Если же первое слово не совпадает с заранее заданным именем, то выводится сообщение "запрос к кому-то еще".

В коде это реализовано через цикл for и операторы if и else. Под else как раз записаны случаи, когда первое слово вопроса не совпадает с заранее заданным именем.
Проблема в том, что else не срабатывает и программа ведет себя так, как будто во всех вопросах в начале стоит нужное имя.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и что нужно исправить?

Вот код:

````
def check_query(query):
    for r in queries:
        r_string = r.split()
    if r_string[0] == 'Анфиса,':
        return ('Запрос к Анфисе')
    else:
        return ('Запрос к кому-то еще')


queries = [
    'Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?',
    'Андрей, ну где ты был?',
    'Андрей, ну обними меня скорей!',
    'Анфиса, кто все мои друзья?'
]

for q in queries:
    result = check_query(q)
    print(q, '-', result)```
````

Answer (score 1):

потому что надо аккуратнее с отступами - у вас условия не в цикле

```
for r in queries:
    r_string = r.split()
if r_string[0] == 'Анфиса,':
    return ('Запрос к Анфисе')
else:
    return ('Запрос к кому-то еще')
```

надо так:

```
for r in queries:
    r_string = r.split()
    if r_string[0] == 'Анфиса,':
        return ('Запрос к Анфисе')
    else:
        return ('Запрос к кому-то еще')
```

P.S.

касательно вашей проблеме

вот правильный код:

```
def check_query(query):
    r_string = query.split()
    if r_string[0] == 'Анфиса,':
        return ('Запрос к Анфисе')
    else:
        return ('Запрос к кому-то еще')


queries = [
    'Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?',
    'Андрей, ну где ты был?',
    'Андрей, ну обними меня скорей!',
    'Анфиса, кто все мои друзья?'
]

for q in queries:
    result = check_query(q)
    print(q, '-', result)
```

у вас в коде было несколько логических ошибок:

в функцию вы передаете параметр `check_query(q)` - элемент списка `queries`, но в самой функции этим параметром не пользуетесь

```
def check_query(query):
    for r in queries:
```

в итоге у вас происходит следующее:

каждый раз в цикле вы извлекаете из своего глобального списка первую запись `Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?`, разбиваете ее на слова и сравниваете с `Анфиса,` и тут же выходите из цикла, не просматривая остальные записи

поэтому функция как бы не вызывалась всегда будет выдавать Анфису

Кроме того, внутри функции вам не нужен никакой цикл, ведь цикл уже есть вне функции, в котором и перебираются записи списка `queries`, а внутри функции нужно только разбить на слова и сравнить с первым словом

P.P.S.

кстати даже не разбивая на слова вы можете сравнить:

```
if r[:7] == 'Анфиса,'
```

Comment: @ Zhihar Согласен. Однако перепроверил у себя в pycharm - там так и было, как Вы предложили - все отступы соблюдены. Видимо, вставилось на форум неправильно. На всякий случай скопировал Вашу часть кода - все равно не срабатывает.

Comment: Нашел я вашу проблему - добавил в конец своего ответа

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый комментарий. Буду разбираться и делать выводы.